# Receiving multi-line input and concatenating it into a single string to do something with in a Java console app

Tags: java, console-application, stringbuilder

The ultimate goal is to take a multi-line user input and combine it all into one single string that can be used later in my code. When I use the code below every sinle line is printed perfectly as output. However, when I use the commented code my end result is not correct.

```
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    // String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // sb1.append(line);
}

// System.out.println(sb1.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming what you want is for a new line after every input so after

`sb1.append(line);`

add

`sb1.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Edit: (because i dont know how to post code in comments)
This will basically keep asking for input until user types in "exit" which it then will break from while loop and print out the string. You can append commas or spaces to separate them after appending line.

I'm not sure if your original problem was because you weren't breaking from loop or because you called `nextLine` twice in print and assigning it to `line`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String input;
            while (!(input = scanner.nextLine()).equals("exit")) {
                sb.append(input);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Comment: My goal is to accept all of the lines and concatenate them into a single string. Which will be used elsewhere in my code.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Hmm what I posted with what you have combined should give you a String with the input + a new line after every input which from what I understand is what you want?

Comment: I don't want to keep the lines. I want it to be a single line string.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Well not exactly sure what format you want but look at main post again

Comment: your answer is exactly what I was trying in my post. If you run the code it doesn't even accept the user input it just goes dead. Which is the issue I am facing. Maybe it is because I am using Java 12... I don't know.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Ah hmm.. I wrote this using Java 8 and just tested with 11 and worked so not too sure. How are you running this?

Comment: I think my issue this entire time was not knowing that the user needs to type exit after pasting a multi-line console input. This is fine, but is there anyway to avoid this so the user can just paste and hit enter?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Well if instead of `"exit"` you set the exit string to `""` then after user finishes typing strings they just hit enter again after last string and it'll exit the loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190779/discussion-between-chris-and-blake-rivell).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
private static String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {

 File file = new File(pathname);
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());        

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() );
        }
        return fileContents.toString();
    }
}
```

This code will read all lines from a text file and give us as a single string as return object.

Comment: I am not reading from a file here. I am reading user input in a console app.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the pom.xml file for your reference:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>json_example</groupId>
  <artifactId>json_example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then add maven dependent jar files to your classpath.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a valid JSON string: ");

    try (// Create JsonReader from Json.
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(System.in)) {
        // Get the JsonObject structure from JsonReader.
        JsonObject jsonObj = reader.readObject();
        System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I run the debug in IntelliJ and paste a multi line json string then press enter and no matter how many times a press enter nothing happens. I will give your code a try tomorrow though.

Comment: Maybe it isn't a good idea to have the user paste formatted Json in a console app and I should be doing this a different way like pointing to a file or something. But it should be possible right? My ultimate goal is to pass a user-entered formatted json to final JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(userJsonStr)); Prior to passing it here I need to strip all white spaces and remove all line breaks. Otherwise the parser will error.

Comment: I think inputting **Json in a console app** would be just for testing and debugging purpose.